# exclude assembly from build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, compilation, .net-assembly

I have a solution file with 10 assemblies. When I build the solution I would like to exclude 5 of them from being built and put in the Release folder. I tried going into the properties of the solution and unticking the assemblies in the Build column in the configuration properties, but this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If may use Configuration Manager tool of visual studio by write clicking on your solution in VS and selecting  Configuration Manager and in active solution configuration combo box  selection `New`
deselecting any project.
[image]

More configuration options for this newly created build will be possible by right clicking on each project any selecting properties part and going to Build tab(like output path will be editable)
[image]